# How to improve slow performance when routes to a new page from a heavy loaded highcharts page with react

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-router

I am using react, react router, and highcharts. I have a result page loaded with 50 highchart graphs, each graph contains 1k to 10k points. The performance in general is good except in one scenario: when I click a link from result page to any other page, it takes about 4-10 seconds. There is no remote action, all the time is taken by the browser. When I reduce the charts on page from 50 to 10, the performance is improved to under 1 second.

I wonder if there is anyway to improve the performance while keeping the current design?

More info:

1. No error from console. It is only slow with chrome browser, safari is much faster.
2. Passed data points in as props, intermediate components are pure components.

Comment: Do you use any errors in the console (dev tools)? Have you tried to use the Highstock ?

Comment: No error in the console.

Comment: How you add new points and modify series? by series.update / setData or in other way? Have you a live demo of you chart, anywhere?

Comment: I use  `<ReactHighcharts config = {configVar} />`. Data points are passed in as props.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of why it was so slow Jay? Facing similar issues